# Destroy sprite body when they reached at some point

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

How can i destroy sprite when they reached at some point.
I know the code of destroy sprite but dont know the condition.
My sprite move through acceleration and i want to destroy that sprite when they reached at botton right corner of screen...

please give me a code or hint what to do. please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you get the position of your sprite get execute the below code to delete the boxBody. It is for the cocos2D with Box2D Physics. **Use the Tag when you add the Sprite to layer,** based on the tag the deletion of Body would be done. The sprite is not Removed with this code.

```
-(void) deleteBoxBody :(int) passTag 
{

    for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {

        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {

            CCSprite *temp1 = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();

            if(temp1.tag == passTag)
            {
//              NSLog(@"Destroying here");
                _world->DestroyBody(b);
                [self removeChild:temp1 cleanup:YES];

                return;
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is called sprite culling.

You can do it several ways. Here you have a couple of simple approaches:

1. Schedule a sprite culler that evaluates the position of all the sprites you might want to kill, and remove them form the screen. Adjust the schedule time as necessary according to the precision you need to achieve.
2. Make the culler a node (or a series of nodes) and place it offscreen. Provide collision detection so you can detect when the sprites reach the culler. When the sprites collide with the culler, it can remove them from screen.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to avoid crash. Safe and timed destroy.

```
-(void) tick: (ccTime) dt
{
    ...
    std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
    std::vector<b2Body *>::iterator pos;

    for (b2Body* b = _world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
    {

        if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
        {

            CCSprite *temp1 = (CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();

            if(temp1.tag == kTagSpriteOnWish)
            {
             temp1.tag = kTagExpiredSprite;
                     temp1.visible = false;
   [self performSelector:@selector(removeSprite:)  withObject: temp1 afterDelay:1.5]; 

                 toDestroy.push_back(b);                 
            }               
        }
    }

for (pos = toDestroy.begin(); pos!=toDestroy.end(); ++pos) 
    {
        b2Body *body = *pos;     
        world->DestroyBody(body);
        body= NULL;
    }
}

-(void)removeSprite:(id)sender
{
    CCSprite *spr = (CCSprite*)sender;
    [spr removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
    [spr removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];

//    printf("Removed ice block\n");
}
}
```